# simplexml_load_file/simplexml_load_string both return wrong informations

Tags: php, xml, curl

I try to get the content of the following URI

```
https://api.alamy.com/images/api/v2/search?IncPU=1&IncEdOnly=1&qt=BJ2206&pn=1&pgs=7
```

When I open it in my brownser I get xml as expected.

```xml
<IMAGES>
  <I ID="{59E6A15C-988E-4893-A5F5-24A58253C054}" AR="BJ2206" LI="2" MR="0" PR="0" R="0" PIX_X="5197" PIX_Y="3465" TYPE="image" PREMIUM="0" CAPTION="Barbary Lion (Panthera leo leo), lying male." LC="en" DATETAKEN="20090603" P="31467" T="1" FLP="0" DATACO="0" seocontribpriority="1"/>
  <RESULTS IMAGES="1" AGENCIES="0" SEARCH_TYPE_SI="" HARD_CLASS="false" COLLECTIONS="0" CDS="0" BESTOF="0" COMMCOUNT="0" CUSTCOUNT="0" TOTALAGENCYIMAGES="0" TOTALPHOTOGRAPHERIMAGES="0" AGENCYIMAGES="0" AGENCY="0" ST="0"/>
</IMAGES>
```

The problem is when I load that URI using cURL some informations are missing or wrong regarding thoses displayed in the browser.

```php
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
# https://api.alamy.com/images/api/v2/search?IncPU=1&IncEdOnly=1&qt=BJ2206&pn=1&pgs=7 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$xmlresponse = curl_exec($ch);
$xml=simplexml_load_string($xmlresponse);
```

Output

```sh
[21-Oct-2020 10:17:35 Europe/Paris] SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [RESULTS] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [IMAGES] => 0
                    [AGENCIES] => 0
                    [SEARCH_TYPE_SI] =>
                    [HARD_CLASS] =>
                    [COLLECTIONS] => 0
                    [CDS] => 0
                    [BESTOF] => 0
                    [COMMCOUNT] => 0
                    [CUSTCOUNT] => 0
                    [TOTALAGENCYIMAGES] => 0
                    [TOTALPHOTOGRAPHERIMAGES] => 0
                    [AGENCYIMAGES] => 0
                    [AGENCY] => 0
                    [ST] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

What the problem could be ? From API's side ? From php and/or my code ?

Comment: It is working perfectly fine with me and giving correct output. Make sure you are not modifying somewhere else. In my case I'm getting both `I` and `RESULT` as keys but in your case that is not the case.

Comment: I tried that code on another host and it works like a charm. I'm sure that nothing is modified somewhere else..so the problem could be from server's configuration ? or php ?